# Passar parâmetro em View

Tags: mysql, parâmetros, sql-view

Como faço para passar um parâmetro para uma *view* no MySQL? Utilizando o SQL Server bastava colocar `WHERE u.nome = @nome` que resolveria o problema. Segue abaixo a *view* do problema em SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW `view_conta_pessoa` AS SELECT p.nome, p.email FROM conta c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON p.id = c.pessoa_id WHERE c.login = @parametro
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não há como passar parâmetros para uma `view` no **MySQL**. [Mais detalhes podem ser vistos na documentação oficial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

Existem algumas *formas alternativas* de definir o `where` de uma `view` dinamicamente.

- #### Criar uma `function`

  ```
  create function funcao() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @funcao;
  ```

  Depois criar a `view`, referenciando a `function` como cláusula `where` e então chamar a função como se fosse um parâmetro:

  ```
  CREATE VIEW `view_conta_pessoa` AS SELECT p.nome, p.email 
  FROM conta c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON p.id = c.pessoa_id WHERE c.coluna = funcao();
  ```

  E, por fim, é possível "chamar a `view` com um parâmetro"

  ```
  select p.* from (select @funcao:=12 f) s, view_conta_pessoa p;
  ```

[Veja funcionando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd6514)

- #### Usar uma cláusula `where`

  É possível também possível colocar uma cláusula `where` na **chamada da `view`**:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM view_conta_pessoa c WHERE c.login = 'login'
  ```

Resposta adaptada [deste post do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessariamente verdade que não passamos parâmetros para uma view. É bem verdade que que não conseguimos definir parâmetros (bom, pelo menos em minhas experiências não rolou). Mas quem disse que precisamos?

Observe a view, com alguns joins:

```
    CREATE 
VIEW `view_ranking_candidato` AS
    SELECT 
        `candidato`.`nick` AS `nick`,
        `candidato`.`nomeCompleto` AS `nomeCompleto`,
        SUM(`desafios`.`pontuacao`) AS `totalPontos`
    FROM
        (((`acertoCandidato`
        JOIN `respostaSubmetida` ON ((`respostaSubmetida`.`idRespSubmetida` = `acertoCandidato`.`idRespostaSubmetida`)))
        JOIN `desafios` ON ((`desafios`.`idDesafio` = `acertoCandidato`.`idDesafio`)))
        JOIN `candidato` ON ((`candidato`.`idCandidato` = `respostaSubmetida`.`idCandidato`)))
    GROUP BY `candidato`.`idCandidato`
```

Caso queira fazer uma busca parametrizada, basta incluir a cláusula where no select que vai consumir a view:

```
select * from view_ranking_candidato ---> vai executar a view sem parâmetros

select * from view_ranking_candidato Where nick='tester' ---> vai executar a view incluindo a cláusula where.
```

Adaptado de:
http://profvictorhugo.esy.es/bd/mysql/mysql-view-tutorial/

Comment: Pelo menos cite as partes importantes **aqui**, e não de uma resposta somente com link.

Comment: Legal a sua iniciativa de responder a pergunta mas da forma que está parece spam. O que acha de [edit] a reescrever a resposta pode colocar as partes relevantes do seu post nela e deixar o link como complemento. Quando tiver um tempo recomendo a leitura de: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/91)

Comment: Correto, pessoal. Alterei!

Comment: Acredito que a edição da resposta original do LINQ deixou mais claro agora, no ponto onde tentei contribuir.