# duvida VIEW MySQL

Tags: mysql

Em uma tabela eu tenho as seguintes colunas: `nomeAluno`, `disciplina`, `numeroDeFaltas`.

Preciso de uma *VIEW* que eu possa colocar o nome do aluno na clausula `WHERE` e ela me retorne o nome da disciplina que este aluno tem menos faltas, tipo assim:

```
SELECT disciplina
FROM nomeView
WHERE nomeAluno = 'Marcos';
```

Comment: Numa `VIEW` não consegue ter parâmetros. Para isso terá que criar uma `Stored Procedure`.

Comment: Veja por exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75962/passar-par%c3%a2metro-em-view
Como o João Martins indicou, não é possível passar parâmetros para uma view

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso o que você esta precisando, uma VIEW aonde você coloca um aluno no WHERE e retorna qual disciplina ele tem menos falta. Uma VIEW nada mais é que um SELECT montado que será sempre utilizado, ou seja, ao invés de você ficar sempre montando SELECT complexo do zero aonde pode ter N tabelas, você apenas chama a sua VIEW. Pelo que pude entender você quer montar um script (select) aonde ao receber um aluno ele retorne a disciplina com menos falta, se for um select simples não é nem necessário uma VIEW. Caso precise de ajuda para montar esse SELECT, coloque aqui as tabelas que v

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar parâmetro em View](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75962/passar-par%c3%a2metro-em-view)